# rtk-query mutation rejected

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

am testing rtk-query in one of my projects and there's a problem that i don't understand when the website load for the first time query work and the data get received however when i try to update or create anything i get in redux dev tools mutation status rejected but when i refresh the website and i try  again it work so the problem occur only when the website load for the first time and this is my code

```
// import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query';

import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

const auth = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth'));

export const crudApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_API,
    // prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
    //   console.log(headers);
    // },
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getList: builder.query({
      query: (path) => ({
        url: `${path}/list`,
      }),
    }),
    checkCopon: builder.mutation({
      query: (code) => ({
        url: `copon/check`,
        body: { code },
        method: 'POST',
      }),
    }),
    filterDishes: builder.mutation({
      query: (tags) => ({
        url: `dish/filter`,
        body: { tags },
        method: 'POST',
      }),
    }),
    getTodaysOrders: builder.query({
      query: () => ({
        url: `order/todayList`,
        body: { today: true },
        method: 'POST',
      }),
    }),
    getSingle: builder.query({
      query: ({ path, id }) => {
        console.log(path, id);
        return {
          url: `${path}/get`,
          body: { id },
          method: 'POST',
        };
      },
    }),
    listOrderByUser: builder.query({
      query: (id) => {
        console.log(id);
        return {
          url: `order/listByUser`,
          body: { id },
          method: 'POST',
        };
      },
    }),
    docUpdate: builder.mutation({
      query: (body) => {
        console.log(body);
        return {
          url: `${body.path}/update`,
          body: body,
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + auth.token,
          },
        };
      },
    }),
    Add: builder.mutation({
      query: (body) => {
        console.log(body);

        return {
          url: `${body.path}/add`,
          body: body,
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + auth.token,
          },
        };
      },
    }),
    Delete: builder.mutation({
      query: (body) => {
        console.log(body);
        console.log(`${body.path}/delete`);
        return {
          url: `${body.path}/delete`,
          body: { ids: body.ids },
          method: 'POST',
        };
      },
    }),
  }),
});

// Export hooks for usage in functional components
export const {
  useListOrderByUserQuery,
  useGetListQuery,
  useGetSingleQuery,
  useDocUpdateMutation,
  useDeleteMutation,
  useAddMutation,
  useGetTodaysOrdersQuery,
  useCheckCoponMutation,
  useFilterDishesMutation,
} = crudApi;
```

if anyone can help ill be thankful i don't want to rewrite all the code to fix it

Answer (score 3):

A rejected action in the devtools, can mean a lot of things, including "we don't need to make a new request for this data as it is already in the cache".

You will get more information by inspecting that action further (especially `action.meta` - if `action.meta.condition` is `true`, then it is as I said and there was just no need for a new request) or just look at the `error` you got back from calling your hook.

But without more information about the error (if there is one), it's impossible to say more.